# When use pyserial reading serial port hex string value, it can't get right responsing answer

Tags: python, linux, pyserial

```
[Motor driver modbus protocol information][1]
[Our Motor driver electric scripts ][2]
[Device address and Register information ][3]
```

I know that I need to use encode to transfer my **hex** string, I try so many ways to get correct value but not right at all.

**For example:**
When I send **hex** string (such as  `"03060000000149e8"`) to my port:
It should response `"03 06 00 00 00 01 49 e8"` which I got from cutecom a serial port assistant, but It only gave me `"0310000152ff"`.

I have no idea about it, could you help me to fix this? Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import serial
import time

import binascii
import struct

s=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',19200,bytesize=8, parity='O', stopbits=1,timeout=None, xonxoff=0)#

message_bytes = "03060000000149e8".decode('hex'
# print str(message_bytes)
s.write(message_bytes)
s.flushInput()
s.flushOutput()
time.sleep(0.1)
# print s.read(1)

# print bytes(s.read(15))#.encode('hex')
# print binascii.hexlify(s.read(15))

serial_data =''
while s.inWaiting() > 0:
    c=s.read(1)
    # or    c=ser.read(1).decode('latin1')
    serial_data += c
    s.flushOutput()
    print hex(int(c.encode('hex'),16))
    # w = struct.unpack("h", c)[0]
    # print w
    # print binascii.hexlify(c)
    # print int(c,16)
print serial_data.encode('hex')
print binascii.hexlify(serial_data.replace('\n',''))#.decode('hex')

# message_bytes_2='03060002ff9c6871'.decode("hex")
# # kk="\x01\x06\x00\x02\x03\xE8\x28\xB4"
# s.write(message_bytes_2)
# time.sleep(0.01)
#
# print s.read(15).encode('hex')
# s.reset_output_buffer()
# message_bytes_2='030300000002c5e9'.decode("hex")
# # kk="\x01\x06\x00\x02\x03\xE8\x28\xB4"
# print s.write(message_bytes_2)
# time.sleep(0.1)
#

s.close()


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkXkv.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkdWK.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClSjN.png
```

Comment: How are you imagining that anybody would be able to help you without knowing ANYTHING about the device you're communicating with?  For all we know, it's *supposed* to switch between those two responses, based on the day of the week or the phase of the moon...

Comment: I'm so sorry and thank you for your quick replying. Serial port mainly communicates with a motor driver, and I upload some device and register information to here, I translate some main information in English:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkXkv.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkdWK.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClSjN.png
My question is why I couldn't get right response result, Such as if I write  "03060000000149e8" to serial port, I should get "03 06 00 00 00 01 49 e8"
But as you can see, I get "0310000152ff".
At last, if you wanna more information , Please let me konw, Thanks

Comment: @jasonharper Hi, can you give me some ideas about this?

Comment: Hi all, I have solved this problem when I read the tutorial more than three times, My driver is not supported for hardware flow or software flow, So when I set them all false, Everything is OK! Thank you!